# Pod not started after sidecar injection manually using istio

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

I am getting below error while trying to inject istio sidecar container manually to pod.

- Kubernetes version v1.21.0
- Istio version : 1.8.0

**Installation commands:-**

```
kubectl create namespace istio-system

helm install --namespace istio-system istio-base istio/charts/base

helm install --namespace istio-system istiod istio/charts/istio-control/istio-discovery --set global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt
```

In kubectl get events, I can see below error:

```
Error creating: admission webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io" denied the request: template: inject:443: function "appendMultusNetwork" not defined
```

In kube api server logs, below errors are observed:

```
W0505 02:05:30.750732 1 dispatcher.go:142] rejected by webhook "validation.istio.io": &errors.StatusError{ErrStatus:v1.Status{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ListMeta:v1.ListMeta{SelfLink:"", ResourceVersion:"", Continue:"", RemainingItemCount:(*int64)(nil)}, Status:"Failure", Message:"admission webhook \"validation.istio.io\" denied the request: configuration is invalid: gateway must have at least one server", Reason:"", Details:(*v1.StatusDetails)(nil), Code:400}}
```

Please let me know if any clue on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I went over step-by-step installation with official documentation, and could not reproduce your problem.
Here are a few things worth checking:

- Did you executed all the commands correctly?
- Maybe you run a different version of Istio? You can check by issuing `istioctl version` command
- Maybe you changed something in config files? If you did, what exactly?
- Try the latest version of Istio (1.9)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response .

1. Instead of helm charts now i refer  official doc for install with istioctl .

   istioctl install --manifests=manifests/ 
   
   I have used manifests since i am installing on offline system hence i downloaded 1.9.4 
  pilot image and pushed in my private repo. 
   
   I modified the yaml files just to chnage the repo from docker.io to my private repo and logs level . Also i disabled ingress gateway  
   
2. This the reposne from istioctl version.

 client version: 1.9.4
     control plane version: 9541********
    data plane version: none

Comment: Now i got below error :  Error creating: admission webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io" denied the request: template: inject:1: function "Template_Version_And_Istio_Version_Mismatched_Check_Installation" not defined

Comment: This error indicates you are using older version of istiod image. Also, that's a weird control plane and data plave versions. Output after default isntallation should look like this
`client version: 1.9.4
control plane version: 1.9.4
data plane version: 1.9.4 (1 proxies)`
Maybe try uninstalling Istio and install it again?